# shredding of XML in SQl Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

I have the XML File in following format,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
   <Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Name xmlns="http://localhost">Reshma</Name>
    <BirthDate xmlns="http://localhost">1988-09-23T00:00:00</BirthDate> 
   </Data>
```

when I am using XML task to just get single node value that is name, the screen shot of XML Task is as follows,

[image]

after this transformation, I get the Xml data in the following format,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Data><Name>Rahul</Name><BirthDate>1988-09-23T00:00:00</BirthDate></Data>
```

But still I am not able to get the single node value of Name node,
Can anyone explain what exactly is happening above and what I am suppose to do to get exactly the single node value.
Since , I am badly stuck, any sort of help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below SQL.

```
DECLARE @x xml ;

SELECT @x = REPLACE(REPLACE(BulkColumn,CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'')
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'E:\SQL_Queries\test.xml', SINGLE_NCLOB) AS X

SELECT 
T.c.value('.','nvarchar(50)') AS result
FROM   @x.nodes('//*[local-name()="Data"]/*[local-name() = "Name"]') T(c);
GO
```

Comment: @Reshma : Updated the answer. Please have a look

Comment: Aggrawal...that is the basic problem , actually I am not able to remove that root xml node ,but anyways thanks a lot for this solution, I will try on this.

Comment: @Reshma: Already updated the answer. Now you do not need to remove the root xml node.

Comment: Aggrawal.. what if this xml file is in the file format saved in any drive or else I have saved the whole of this xml file in any column of table, then how I am suppose to get the required value

Comment: Aggrawal.. can you please help me with this query, actually this xml file I am getting as result from web service task that I have saved as xml file on system,my main aim is to store the values individually into columns of table, tried various different ways bt not able to solve that

Comment: @Reshma :Do you want me this from xml file or table coulumn field?

Comment: Aggrawal...I want to do this from XML file

Comment: Aggrawal... actually my aim is I am using a web service task in SSIS where I am storing the result in XML file, from this XML file I have to store both the values name as well as birth date into database, but since I was unable to save both of them I was trying for single value to retrieve it and store, if you can store both the value in different columns in database then I will be very much thankful to you.

Comment: Updated the sql query. Please have a look

Comment: Aggrawal.. what will be the query if I want to select both the values name as well as birthdate..??